# When executing a batch file from c# with the window hidden, programs that are executed by the batch file won't start

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to write a small tool (called `StartProcess.exe`) in C# that allows me to execute batch files without the cmd window showing. It uses the following code (excerpt from Main()):

```
        Process process = new Process();

        // Stop the process from opening a new window
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        // Setup executable and parameters
        process.StartInfo.FileName = args[0];

        // Go
        process.Start();
```

Unfortunately, this does not work as intended. When I try to use the tool in a shortcut on the desktop to execute a small batch file (`test.bat`) that tries to start notepad, nothing happens. 
When I try `StartProcess notepad` on a cmd prompt, it works.

Does anybody know or have an educated guess what could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: to begin with test once after setting the `WorkingDirectory` property to the path of the batch script.

Comment: To begin with, I had to change my initial post. Executing a batch script does not work at all, however directly executing notepad via my tool does. And to your suggestion: Changing the working directory does unfortunately not change anything as well.

Comment: Well, I found the problem. My tool exits directly after starting the process, therefore killing all child processes as well. When adding `process.WaitForExit()` at the end, everything works as expected. Feeling pretty stupid now...  Well, thanks for your time and your answers!

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly for me when using a "console application" and with "windows application", using DotNet 4 Client Profile.

```
Process process = new Process();

// Stop the process from opening a new window
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

// Setup executable and parameters
process.StartInfo.FileName = "batch.bat";

// Go
process.Start();
```

where batch.bat is in the same folder my program and contains just a line:

```
notepad
```

And when my program end, the notepad is still open...

If you change your application from "Console Application" for "Windows Application", the above code seems to not work.
But if you add Thread.Sleep(1000); at the end, after the process.Start();, it works as expected. The Nopepad is opened and the program finishes.

Comment: Which is basically just the same code as mine. What differences could there be? Do you have differing settings in your Properties? I'm using .net 4.0 Client Profile, compiling as Windows Application.

Comment: Well, that makes sense in a way, since a console application is supposed to exit only when it has completed its work. But did your program open a window itself, even without any output? That would again defeat the purpose of my program, which is why I chose "Windows Application" in the first place :)

Comment: @pmuench, I just tested with a "Windows Application" and it worked the same way... I put a buttom in the windows that executes the code with the process. It opens the notepad. I close the window and the notepad still is open. Which is what I'm expecting, because the notepad is not a "child process". It is a process on it's own... No?

Comment: Did you create a new Windows Forms project? In that case, afaik the main thread of the program is responsible for executing the Main() only, which spawns the GUI and corresponding event handling thread and exits afterwards, while the program is still running. In that case, it may be that the event handling thread waits for all child processes to exit before exiting itself. My program started as a console application, and I manually changed to compiling it as a "Windows Application" in the properties of the project.

Comment: No, I found the problem. It's because your "process" object is being killed too fast, before the process can actually be lauched, but I don't know way this happens when it's a "Windows Applicatin" but not when it's a "Console Application". But the application finishes and the lauched program is still open.

Comment: Yes, that could be the reason as well. I don't know enough of the internals of .net to make a guess about the actual reason, but as long as I have a sensible solution to a problem, I do not try to put too much effort into researching why it works now and didn't before ;)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution myself. My tool exits directly after `process.Start()` and  simultaneously kills all its child processes. When adding a `process.WaitForExit()`after the `process.Start()`, it works as expected.

Note: as you can see from the answers below, this seems to be needed only when compiling as a "Windows Application".

```
    Process process = new Process();

    // Stop the process from opening a new window
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

    // Setup executable and parameters
    process.StartInfo.FileName = args[0];

    // Go
    process.Start();
    process.WaitForExit();
```